# Jaynes Probability Theory 6.44 (May be it is an error) help

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

I read about this,
$$ p(R|r=0,NI_{1}) = {N\choose n+1}{N-R\choose n} \; (6.44)$$
but the probability can not be greater than 1, this expression is an apparent error.
$I_{1}$ means the state of knowledge about the urn is that 0 < R < N, while the general sum $S = \sum_{R=0}^N{{R\choose0}{N-R\choose n-r}}= {N+1\choose n+1} $ is given by $I_{0}$ which means we do not know the state of the knowledge about urn at all, so the $S'= S - {N\choose n}\delta(r,0) - {N\choose n}\delta(r,n)$, and the S' should be the denominator.
Finally i get the result is
$$ p(R|r=0,NI_1) = \frac{N-R\choose n}{N\choose n +1}$$

Comment: This question is not readable without getting back to the book and should be made self-contained.

Comment: Yes, when I come across problem while reading the book, i will post a question here. I will make question more clear next time.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this error discussed (along with many others) at the website http://ksvanhorn.com/bayes/index.html.
For more information on Jaynes's book, see http://www.etjaynesinfo.com

Comment: Thank you!  It would be better if you would edit this post to cite the specific error that was made, rather than requiring interested readers to follow the links.